# load the content of different html pages in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When user selects the link, i want to load the content of other html inside the same page as per user slection.
 The links provided are inside a controller(myController). How to load the red.html and green.html based on the
 user selection. The below js code works if the links are not inside the ng-controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myController">
<a href="#!red">Red</a>
<a href="#!green">Green</a>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.html"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.html"
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PS: I want the links to be inside `ng-controller="myController"` and based on the user selection i want to load the html page in the same page.
If i remove ng-controller from div, it is loading the content but i want the links to be inside the controller as shown in the above code.

Comment: It is unclear, please update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was you didn't implement your controller as below.

```
//DEFINE THE CONTROLLER
////////////////////////////////
app.controller("myController", function(){

});
```

Look at the following example and it's working perfectly.
Also I modified `templateUrl` to `template` just for demonstrate purposes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <a href="#!red">Red</a>
    <a href="#!green">Green</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

    //DEFINE THE CONTROLLER
    ////////////////////////////////
    app.controller("myController", function() {

    });

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
          template: "<h1>Home</h1>"
        })
        .when("/red", {
          template: "<h1>Red</h1>"
        })
        .when("/green", {
          template: "<h1>Green</h1>"
        })
        .when("/blue", {
          template: "<h1>Blue</h1>"
        });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```